# Add value to :after element in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

Hy, I have all the code, but I have no clue how to add it to :after elements. It's probably easy,here's the code:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var imageSrc = document
                    .getElementById('bg_head')
                     .style
                      .backgroundImage
                       .replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2')
                        .split(',')[0];    

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;

    var width = image.width,
        height = image.height;
        asp=height / width;
        $('#bg_head').append('<style>#bg_head:before{padding-top:'asp';}</style>');
}
```

You probably see what I'm trying to do. Add the asp calculated value to the padding-top or bottom of a :after element. But I don't know how to fix the code. I just need to convert everything to jquery I think? 
Thanks

Comment: it would be more like '<style>#bg_head:before{padding-top:'+(asp*100)+'%;}</style>'

Comment: This question might help, although I haven't tried it myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after

Comment: Add two + operators in your last codeline like so: `$('#bg_head').append('<style>#bg_head:before{padding-top:' + asp + ';}</style>');`